# Question related to the proof of "If $c>0$, then $\lim {c^{1/n}}=1$"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

To do this proof, for $c>1$, $c^{1/n}=1+d_n$, and for $0<c<1$, $c^{1/n}=\frac{1}{1+h_n}$, where $d_n>0$, and, $h_n>0$ respectively.

I am having trouble understanding why we can write these equations. Which rules assert these?

Without knowing the rules, these equations seem to appear out of blue.

Comment: What are you really confused about? That we are _allowed_ to define $d_n$ and $h_n$ like that, or that it is _productive_ to define $d_n$ and $h_n$ like that?

Comment: If $n→∞$ then $Lim (1/n)→0$ ...So $Lim _{n→∞}C^{(1/n)}=C^0=1$

Comment: <In response to Arthur> I got my answer. My confusion was, from where $d_n$ and $h_n$ come. The text book jumped a few steps, and I had trouble understanding it.

Comment: If $a >b $ then we can define $m=b-a $.  $m>0$ and $b=a +m $.  I hope that is clear.  That is just assigning labels rewriting them.  So is $c>1$ we have a proposition that $c^{\frac12} >1$.  So we let $d_n=c^{\frac 12}-1$.  And if $b>1$ that means $\frac 1b >1$. So if $c <1$ we have a propsition that $c^{\frac 12}<1$.  So $\frac 1 {c^{\frac12}}>1$.  So they let $h_n=1-\frac 1 {c^{\frac12}} $.

Comment: Although you have an A, remember that we can make up definitions any  way we please, If you see something like " $c>1\implies c^{1/n}=1+d_n$ where $d_n>0$ " you are seeing a definition of $d_n$ and an assertion about its properties in the same sentence. It is easier to write than "Define $d_n=c^{1/n}-1.$  If $c>1$ then $d_n>0.$" And perhaps easier to digest, once you're used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because if $c>1$, then $c^{1/n}>1$, so we let $d_{n}=c^{1/n}-1$, then it turns out that $c^{1/n}=1+d_{n}$. Similarly, since $0<c<1$, then $0<c^{1/n}<1$, then $\dfrac{1}{c^{1/n}}>1$ and we let $h_{n}=\dfrac{1}{c^{1/n}}-1>0$.

Comment: User284331.Nice, clear, to the point.+